# Is there a tool to graph a function and have it compute its actual formula?

Tags: graphing-functions

> Is there a tool to graph a function and have it compute its actual formula?

Thank you for your time beforehand.

As the question implies, I want to identify the actual function, not the type, given a graph, for example the following

**Random curve:**

[image]

Is there such a tool that accepts a freely drawn graph and returns the actual function?

Thank you sincerely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Wolfram Mathematica 13.0*, after defining the following function:

```
ExtractData[source_, color_, x0_, y0_, Δx_, Δy_] :=

  Module[{col, data, dist, image, max, pos},
         
         image = Import[source];
         col = DominantColors[image, ColorCoverage -> .001];
         dist = ColorDistance[col, color];
         pos = Position[dist, Min[dist]][[1, 1]];
   
         data = Sort[PixelValuePositions[image, col[[pos]], .01]];
         data = Transpose[data] - First[data];
   
         max = {Max[data[[1]]], Max[data[[2]]]};
         Transpose[{x0, y0} + data {Δx, Δy} / max]
   
        ];
```

just write:

```
data = ExtractData["https://i.postimg.cc/hPy7F3bg/cwJqf.png", Black, 0.9, 2.0, 6.7, 3.0];

fdata = FindFormula[data, x]

ListPlot[{data, Table[{x, fdata}, {x, 0.9, 7.6, .001}]}, 
         AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
         GridLines -> Automatic,
         PlotRange -> {{0, 7.6}, {0, 5.0}},
         PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
```

to obtain:

> -18.8816 + 58.3367 x - 67.3671 x^2 + 44.3662 x^3 - 18.1375 x^4 + 4.76048 x^5 - 0.802839 x^6 + 0.084062 x^7 - 0.00497126 x^8 + 0.000126869 x^9

[image]

which is "the best function" (at least according to *Mathematica algorithms*) that approximates the points of the approximate starting graph (in black the start graph, almost completely superimposed by the red end graph).

The power of `FindFormula` is that it almost instantly manages to identify the type of function that best approximates the *experimental data* among a multitude (obtainable by sum, product, composition, inversion of basic functions, i.e. polynomials, trigonometric, exponential functions). In fact, having decided to approximate the data with a ninth degree polynomial, it's sufficient to apply the **least squares method**:

```
{xi, yi} = Transpose[data];

NMinimize[Total[(yi - (a + b xi + c xi^2 + d xi^3 + e xi^4 + 
                 f xi^5 + g xi^6 + h xi^7 + i xi^8 + j xi^9))^2], 
          {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}]
```

by which the coefficients are quickly calculated:

> {0.254024, {a -> -18.9847, b -> 58.6824, c -> -67.8439, d -> 44.7225, e -> -18.2975, f -> 4.80554, g -> -0.810858, h -> 0.0849365, i -> -0.00502458, j -> 0.000128261}}

which are essentially the same as those obtained automatically.

Of course, no one forbids to settle for a polynomial with a lesser degree, essentially this depends on the circumstances in which one operates. Anyway, by adding this other simple code:

```
frames = Table[coeff = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin["c", ToString[i]]], {i, 0, n}];
               fdata = Total[coeff Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}]];
               sol = NMinimize[Total[(y - fdata)^2 /. {x -> xi, y -> yi}], coeff][[2]];
               ListPlot[{data, Table[{x, fdata /. sol}, {x, 0.9, 7.6, .001}]}, 
                         AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
                         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
                         GridLines -> Automatic,  
                         PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[StringJoin["polynomial of degree ", 
                                                     ToString[n]], Red], {.5, .5}],
                         PlotRange -> {{0, 7.6}, {0, 5.0}},
                         PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}], 
               {n, 0, 9}];

Export["animation.gif", frames, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1];
```

you can visually realize how "wrong" you are:

[image]